# Filtrar preguntas recientes por Etiquetas favoritas (respondidas o sin responder)

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, preguntas

Esto de antemano por lo que veo no es posible. Solo puedo filtrar por mis etiquetas si busco preguntas sin responder y OJO, se ordenan con un criterio que no es posible modificar, no hay manera que salga la más reciente antes.

¿Existe alguna manera de que pueda filtrar solo por mis Etiquetas favoritas ordenadas de más recientes a más antiguas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si en el buscador introduces tus etiquetas favoritas entre corchetes "`[ ]`" tal que `[js]`, entonces busca solo para preguntas que contengan esa etiqueta. En la [resultado de la búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&pageSize=15) te dejará ordenar por recientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si además concatenas etiquetas como `[js][python]`, será una comprobación AND donde solo aparecerán publicaciones con ambas etiquetas pero poniendo `[js] or [python]` saldrán publicaciones que al menos tengan una de las etiquetas.

Comment: Genial!! `[js] or [python]` no sabia que esto se podía hacer!!! Graciassss

Answer (score 2):

En la caja de búsqueda de Stack Overflow en español escribe el operador y palabra clave

`intags:mine`

haz clic en buscar y luego haz clic en la pestaña recientes, o bien usa el enlace siguiente:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine

Referencia

- [¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)